# Include existing C++ enum to namespace

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

I'm trying to use **existing 3rd party** `enum` type of the form:

```
enum EnumType 
{
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
}
```

in my project with two usages:

1. in some files I would like to import this `enum` and put it into an existing namespace (e.g "`namespace myproject`").
2. in file `API.h` I would like to import this `enum` just to declare method with return type of this `enum` (in cpp file I would just make cast from `myproject::EnumType` to `EnumType`)

The reason why I want to do this is that I don't want to put the definition of the `enum` in the API header's namespace.

I have problem with the first point, how can I do it?

Comment: Would it make sense to put the `#include API.h` in the namespace?

Comment: *Why* do you not want to put the definition in the API header's namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Would a `using EnumType` not suffice for your use; a [using-declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)...

```
namespace my_project {
  using ::EnumType;
  //...
}
```

If you still want to "hide" the `EnumType` from being visible in your public API, then you can create an `enum` of your own with the same values and convert between the two in your code.